# How to implement what vaguely is called "database versioning"?

Tags: mysql, yii, backup, restore, database-restore

I write a Web application using Yii framework and MySQL.

Now the boss wants "to store all changes in the database", in order to be able to restore older data if someone destroys some important information in the current version of the data.

What is to store all changes in the database is vague. I am not sure what exactly we should do.

How to fulfill this vague boss's requirement?

Can we do it with MySQL logs? What are pros and contras of using MySQL logs for this? Is it true that we need a programmer (me) to restore some (possibly not all) data from MySQL logs? Can MySQL (partial) data restoration be made simple?

Or should I hard work to manually (not with MySQL logs) store all old data in specific MySQL tables?

Answer (score 3):

I guess what you are describing is an audit trail, which will be handy to go back and look at the history, but as for restoring, that will need to be manual.

Have a look at techniques for creating an audit trail.

Comment: Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104039/way-to-manage-audit-trail-of-changing-record-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [searching the extensions library](http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/) for something like [eactsasversioned](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eactsasversioned) that will archive edits made to records. I'm not sure if it saves deleted records, but it seems like it's close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something you can easily restore from you probably need a backup script run on a very regular basis.  I use a bash script(shown below) in cron to backup the databases I am worried about hourly.  My databases are fairly small so this only takes a few seconds and could be increased to run every 15 minutes if you are super paranoid.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    dbName1="li_appointments"
    dbName2="lidb_users"
    dbName3="orangehrm_li"

    fileName1=$dbName1"_`date +%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S`.sql"
    fileName2=$dbName2"_`date +%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S`.sql"
    fileName3=$dbName3"_`date +%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S`.sql"

    backupDir="/home/backups/mysql"

    mysqldump -u backup_user --password='********************************' $dbName1 > $backupDir/$fileName1
    mysqldump -u backup_user --password='********************************' $dbName2 > $backupDir/$fileName2
    mysqldump -u backup_user --password='********************************' $dbName3 > $backupDir/$fileName3

    bzip2 $backupDir/$fileName1
    bzip2 $backupDir/$fileName2
    bzip2 $backupDir/$fileName3

    gpg -c --passphrase '********************************' $backupDir/$fileName1".bz2"
    gpg -c --passphrase '********************************' $backupDir/$fileName2".bz2"
    gpg -c --passphrase '********************************' $backupDir/$fileName3".bz2"


    rm $backupDir/*.bz2

    echo "Backups completed on `date +%D`" >> $backupDir/backuplog.log
```